# Polynomial - positive roots proof

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

Is it possible for a 3rd-order polynomial with two negative roots and one positive root (e.g., $a > 0, b < 0, c < 0$) to have only positive coefficients?

E.g., 3rd order example:

$s^3 + (a+b+c)s^2 + (ab+bc+ca)s + abc$

The coefficients are : $(a+b+c)$, $(ab+bc+ca)$, $(abc)$.

Comment: If the coefficients of the polynomial are all positive then if you plug in a positive number for $s$ the resulting number will be positive (never zero), hence no positive root.

Comment: @Cauchy : fixed the typo.  Thanks.

Comment: First line asks about the case of `positive coefficients`, then at the end you say `struggling with 2 negative and 1 positive coefficients`. Please clarify what is the actual question you meant to ask.

Comment: @dxiv Done.  Thanks.

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY A polynomial with all the coefficients positive cannot have a positive root (as noted in the first comment already). So, no, it's not possible to have a positive root, regardless of whether the other two are positive, negative or even complex..

Comment: @dxiv Is there a proof for that?  Thanks..

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY By hypothesis, each term of the polynomial is strictly positive when $x \gt 0$. When you add them together, the value will therefore be strictly greater than zero, so no roots $x \gt 0$ can exist.

Comment: @dxiv I am struggling with your answer... (apologies).  What do you mean by adding the terms together?  E.g., a = 10, b = -1, c = -1, a+b+c = 8, still positive.

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY Let the polynomial be $\,P(x)=x^3+px^2+qx+r\,$. You assume the coefficients to be positive, so $\,p,q,r \gt 0\,$. Then for any $\,x \gt 0\,$ it follows that $\,x^3 \gt 0\,$, $\,px^2 \gt 0\,$, $\,q x \gt 0\,$, and of course $\,r \gt 0\,$. Therefore $\,P(x)=x^3+px^2+qx+r \gt 0\,$, so $\,x\,$ cannot be a root of $\,P(x)\,$, and this applies to any $\,x \gt 0\,$. In other words, $\,P(x)=0\,$ cannot have any positive roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.If $ex^3 + gx^2 + hx +j$ be the polynomial in question, then $x > 0 \implies ex^3,gx^2,hx,j$ are all strictly positive quantities, so that their sum is also strictly positive. In other words, the given polynomial doesn't have a positive root at all.

Comment: That's right. thank you for pointing it out @dxiv.